# What does "it" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I came across the following prompt:

> #### Enable location services
>
> You can allow this app to determine your location by enabling **it** in
>   Settings.

Does "it" refer to "determine your location" or "location services"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can allow this app to determine your location by enabling **Location Services** in Settings.
>
> You can allow this app to determine your location by enabling **the feature** in Settings.

It refers to Location Services which is a feature to determine your location.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. The sentence is ambiguously written, and the only way you can work out the answer is by context and, possibly, by checking out the Settings page of the app.

On balance, I am sure it means 'enabling location services'. However, the sentence is badly written.